# Count in laravel by data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, count, laravel-5.1

Here I want to add the data I have based `id_data kos`, so whenever I add data will auto count by `id_data_kos`.

here my controller :

```
$limit = 10;
        $result = DB::table('residents')
        ->join("data_kos","data_kos.id","=","residents.id_data_kos")
        ->select("residents.*","data_kos.title as data_title")
        ->groupBy('id_data_kos')
        ->orderBy('residents.id', 'asc');

$data['posts'] = $result->paginate($limit);
```

and this my view :

```
@foreach($posts as $row)
<td>{{ $row->data_title }}</td>
<td>here i want to count</td>
@endforeach
```

this my table :

[image: this]

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to calculate the count of rows?

Comment: yes,calculate, for example when i input new data with id_data_kos 2 

the id_data_kos will result 2

Comment: Ok you want to count : For each row, the number of records with the same `id_data_kos`? Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$limit = 10;
        $result = DB::table('residents')
        ->join("data_kos","data_kos.id","=","residents.id_data_kos")
        ->select("residents.*","data_kos.title as data_title", DB::raw('COUNT(id_data_kos) as count'))
        ->groupBy('id_data_kos')
        ->orderBy('residents.id', 'asc');

$data['posts'] = $result->paginate($limit);
```

The count of `id_data_kos` will be returned as `count`

Comment: ahh, thats help me now,

Comment: This won't count the number of records with the same `id_data_kos` but anyway.